# I want to push an os to any machines and use task sequence to assign drivers and install different applications.How can i do that?

Tags: sccm

I have done all installations on my home network but I cannot do this.I want to push an os to any machines and use task sequence to assign drivers and install different applications.How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially asking "How do I SCCM?", so I'm afraid all I can suggest is start reading here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg682108.aspx

If you have any more specific questions about problems with the process later then you're welcome to post them.